# ggsurvplot(): showing starting survival below 1

Tags: r, plot, survival

I am analysing the time to the end of rehabilitation; however, not all patients receive rehabilitation. Therefore, for making Kaplan-Meier curves for the whole study population (including non-receivers), these curves should start below survival 1. For example, if only 70% of patients received rehabilitation, y-axis start value should be 0.7. How to make this trick in R? Would it also be possible to make so that all survival tables take into account the non-receivers?

The following graph isn't ideal, as it shows the event happened for 30% of patients on day 0. This isn't true since they never received rehabilitation.

**Generated data and KM curves**

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  time = c(0, 0, 0, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 100, 100),
  status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)

ggsurvplot(fit, data = df)
```

[image]

Comment: maybe you should  remove "never received" rehabilitation from your survival data.
as this has huge impact in median times (50 % of the population at t0), However your median  could be 50 % of the 70% that "received" rehabilitation (35% of the whole pop)

Comment: not receiving rehab is different than what you have coded right now your code says 3 patients received rehab at day 0 which is not the same as no rehab. it is worth exploring the option above or is there an earlier date you can start the km analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the argument `axes.offset = FALSE` like this:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  time = c(0, 0, 0, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 100, 100),
  status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df)

ggsurvplot(fit, data = df, axes.offset = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>